# SQL: Substring/Trim column values based on specific word

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A. How do I trim the column COND so that the values keeps the word ITEM and everything after? I want the results to look like Table B:

Table A

```
|ID   |                        COND                         |
|:--- |:----------------------------------------------------|
|1    |ITEM = 'B967','B677','O342'                          |
|2    |ITEM = 'J833','UR09','ILY7'                          |
|3    |ITEM = 'B967, OJ87'                                  |
|4    |(CATE = 'OBRT', 'TMPT') AND (ITEM = 'UR09','ILY7')   |
|5    |CATE='ONTE,PNTE,QSDW,RVCG' OR ITEM=J833              |
```

Table B

```
|ID   |             COND          |
|:--- |:--------------------------|
|1    |ITEM = 'B967','B677','O342'|
|2    |ITEM = 'J833','UR09','ILY7'|
|3    |ITEM = 'B967, OJ87'        |
|4    |ITEM = 'UR09','ILY7')      |
|5    |ITEM=J833                  |
```

Comment: You don't want that closing paren for ID 4 do you?

Comment: It would be nice if that was removed in the final table too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using REGEXP_SUBSTR() will allow you to capture ITEM and everything up to the last digit character OR a single quote (based on your sample data), thus eliminating that closing paren in ID 4.  Be advised REGEXP_SUBSTR will add more overhead so based on the size of your data this may not be as efficient.  Your mileage may vary.

```
WITH A(ID, cond) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'ITEM = ''B967'',''B677'',''O342''' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ITEM = ''J833'',''UR09'',''ILY7''' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'ITEM = ''B967, OJ87'''             FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '(CATE = ''OBRT'', ''TMPT'') AND (ITEM = ''UR09'',''ILY7'')' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'CATE=''ONTE,PNTE,QSDW,RVCG'' OR ITEM=J833' FROM dual
)
SELECT ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(cond, '(ITEM.*([[:digit:]]|''))') AS ITEM
from a;

   ID ITEM
```

---

```
     1 ITEM = 'B967','B677','O342'                       
     2 ITEM = 'J833','UR09','ILY7'                       
     3 ITEM = 'B967, OJ87'                               
     4 ITEM = 'UR09','ILY7'                              
     5 ITEM=J833
```

5 rows selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of substring and instring. INSTR will return the position where "ITEM" begins, and then SUBSTR will return everything after that position start.

```
select id, cond, SUBSTR(cond, INSTR(cond, 'ITEM', 1)) as col_name
from my_table
```

Output:

| ID | COND | COL_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITEM = 'B967','B677','O342' | ITEM = 'B967','B677','O342' |
| 2 | ITEM = 'J833','UR09','ILY7' | ITEM = 'J833','UR09','ILY7' |
| 3 | ITEM = 'B967, OJ87' | ITEM = 'B967, OJ87' |
| 4 | (CATE = 'OBRT', 'TMPT') AND (ITEM = 'UR09','ILY7') | ITEM = 'UR09','ILY7') |
| 5 | CATE='ONTE,PNTE,QSDW,RVCG' OR ITEM=J833 | ITEM=J833 |

Db-fiddle found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=092983c91d268f7b7d2e99807cfc6a13).

Comment: When I run `SELECT ID, COND, SUBSTR(COND, INSTR(COND, 'ITEM', 1)) AS COND1
FROM A`
I am getting error message: Wrong number of arguments to function INSTR()

Comment: What happens with this query: select INSTR('ABC TRIM 444', 'TRIM', 1) from dual;